# Wrong intersection behavior of opentype math font in ms word

Tags: ms-word, opentype, fontforge

I'm making an opentype math font ([FiraMath](https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath)) for LaTeX and MS Word with FontForge. When creating the `\oint` glyph, I use reference as the following iamge:

[image]

When using the generated otf fonts in LaTeX (actually is XeLaTeX), everything goes right (PDF reader is SumatraPDF):

[image]

But when using MS Word 2016, the intersection behavior is strange:

[image]

Could anyone explain what happened and show how to solve the problem?

GitHub issue link: https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath/issues/6

Comment: Looks like word is interpreting your outline direction as forcing a cutout. You probably want to reverse the direction of your outer and inner circles (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmM98PFovDs) or properly merge your shapes. I had a look at your github repo, there does not appear to be a file that fontforge project in it anywhere?

Comment: I have merged the contours. The fontforge source files are in `src/fira-math-xxx.sfdir`

Comment: looks like you closed the issue, so I guess that means you can delete the question here as well. Or write up an answer if you think that'll benefit future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @be5invis points out in https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath/issues/6,

> Only TTF and CFF2 supports non-zero filling, which allows overlapping contours.

So my solution is simply merge the overlapping contours.